# How to set a default value in the kendo dropdrownlist?

Tags: kendo-ui

When I click **Add new record**, I want the dropdownlist to display the first item of the dropdownlist. I've tried ways, but no luck. I've tried to hard-code the value as the below code shows, but it still no working.

```
function noteTypeDropDownEditor(container, options) {

 var _val = (options.model.NoteTypeId) ? options.model.NoteTypeId : 1;

 $('<input data-text-field="label" data-value-field="id" data-bind="value:' + 
   _val + '" />')
  .appendTo(container)
  .kendoDropDownList({
              autoBind: false,
              dataSource: {
              data: noteTypeData
        }
     })                        
   }
```

Any way to display the fist item as default value if a value is not selected?

Thank for helping

Comment: can u pls share a jsbin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the editor function as:

```
function noteTypeDropDownEditor(container, options) {      
    var _val = (options.model.NoteTypeId) ? options.model.NoteTypeId : 1;
    $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataTextField:"label",
            dataValueField:"id",
            value:_val,
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: {
                data: noteTypeData
            }
        });
}
```

i.e. instead of using declarative initialization, initialize it using JavaScript.